# Lumen 8 Dependency injection - Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to get dependency injection working in Lumen 8 and I'm clearly missing something.  I thought it would be as simple as this...

Make an interface to be injected (an interface so I can change implementation later if I want to)

```
<?php
namespace App\Interfaces;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

interface TestServiceInterface {
    public function sayHello();
}
```

Then make the class (one implementation of the interface)

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;
use App\Interfaces\TestServiceInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class TestService  extends ServiceProvider implements TestServiceInterface
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

Then inject it into the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Interfaces\TestServiceInterface;

class TestsController extends Controller
{
    protected $testService;

    public function __construct(TestServiceInterface $testService)
    {
        //The route rejects requests without token and adds currentUser to request
        $this->testService = $testService;  
    }

    public function useTheSerive()
    {
        return $this->testService->sayHello();
    }

}
```

And from what I have read it sounds like binding was required to let the system know what class is related to what interface. I put this line in the register function of ApplicationProvider.php

```
 $this->app->bind(TestServiceInterface::class, TestService::class);
```

I must still be missing something because I get the error

**Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider**

Can anyone tell me what I am missing??

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is one of the examples where Lumen is different from Laravel.

When you do the binding you have to also inject $app into the concrete class.

```
$this->app->bind(TestServiceInterface::class, function($app) {
        return new TestService($app);
    });
```

I added that line where my service providers were being registered (Providers\AppServiceProviders,php )and it's working now.